# how to re-render React children component when prop that parent pass is changed(redux)

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am little confused with redux and react...

I have parent component(SingleList) that render children component(NutrientsTable). Parent pass to children **productList** piece of state then children in componentDidMount call action that update **currentListNutrients** and then I use that in children render() to show.

I tried declare calculateNutrients as just helper method in component and then assign to variable and then use it in render(). As a result, it work fine but i gonna to put all app actions in Action Creator so I need do it with redux.

Parent Comp **SingleList**

```
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import NutrientsTable from "../NutrientsTable";

class SingleList extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="single-list">
        <NutrientsTable 
          productsList={this.props.list.productsList}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

function mapStateToProps({ lists }, ownProps) {
  return {
    list: lists[ownProps.match.params.id]
  };
}

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  {}
)(SingleList);
```

Children Comp **NutrientsTable**

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { calculateNutrients } from '../actions';

class NutrientsTable extends Component {

    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.calculateNutrients(this.props.productsList);
    }

    render() { 
        const { calories, carbohydrates, proteins, fats } = this.props.nutrients;

        return (
            <div>{calories} {carbohydrates} {proteins} {fats}</div>
        )
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = ({currentListNutrients}) => {
    return { nutrients: currentListNutrients }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { calculateNutrients })(NutrientsTable);
```

Action **calculateNutrients**

```
export function calculateNutrients(productsList) {
  let calories = 0,
    carbohydrates = 0,
    proteins = 0,
    fats = 0;
  _.map(productsList, product => {
    product.calories && (calories += product.calories * product.count);
    product.carbohydrates && (carbohydrates += product.carbohydrates * product.count);
    product.proteins && (proteins += product.proteins * product.count);
    product.fats && (fats += product.fats * product.count);
  });

  return {
    type: CALCULATE_NUTRIENTS,
    payload: {calories, carbohydrates, proteins, fats}
  }
}
```

And **Reducer** just return action.payload

Everything is ok when first render, but when I do some action in parent and change **productList** piece of state then children doesn't re-render with new **productList**. I know is it cause componentDidMount call just one. But where i should call action? I cant resolve it with any lifecycle method. Any suggestion?

Comment: If you intend to update `NutrientsTable` permanently use `componentDidUpdate` as well as `componentDidMount`, as the latter will run only in the initial render. `componentDidUpdate` will run everytime something is... well updated (state or proops). https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate

Comment: Yea I do it with componentDidUpdate, but i put it in parent comp, cause when I put it in children comp here is inifinite loop. But i'm still not sure it is best way to do that

Comment: Keep in mind that you have to do some comparison between the previous props and the new props you want to check. If they are different run the method, otherwise do nothing. Like that you'll avoid an infinite loop. If you still have an infinite loop, that means something else is wrong with your code. If you still run into issues please provide a small reduced sample using codesandbox or stackblitz

Answer (score 1):

First, if you're using Redux, you don't have to pass down data from parent to children if data exists on Redux store (application's state). Just use `connect` for the children components. The children components should update when detecting any changes in Redux store (application's state).

Second, when you want the changes to happen, you have to `dispatch` and action to Redux which tells Redux to call api (or something like that) and update its store.

To handle the api calls, you should use Redux-thunk or Redux-saga.